# Logistic regression implementation not working

Tags: java, machine-learning, logistic-regression

Recently, I have been reading about machine learning of which logistic regression is one. After reading, to test my understanding, I tried to implement LR in Java. When I tested it on Logical OR and Logical AND, it seemed to work. But, when I tried it on marks to decide accepted or rejected job applicants, it failed to learn to classify it. Can you spot what is wrong in this code?

```
public class LogisticRegression {

int featureLength;
ArrayList<Double> inputs = new ArrayList();
int targetOutput;
ArrayList<Double> weights = new ArrayList();
double bias;
static double learningRate = 0.1;

LogisticRegression(int fs) {
    featureLength = fs;
    for (int i = 0; i < featureLength; i++) {
        weights.add(Math.random());
    }

    bias = Math.random();
}

double sigmoidFunction(double x) {
    return 1.0 / (1.0 + Math.exp(-x));
}

double weightedSum() {
    if (inputs.size() != featureLength) {
        System.out.println("Error: input does not match feature length");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < featureLength; i++) {
        double inp = inputs.get(i);
        double wh = weights.get(i);
        sum += inp * wh;
    }

    sum += bias;
    double out = sigmoidFunction(sum);
    return out;
}

void learn() {
    double inp, wh, out, gradient;
    out = weightedSum();
    for (int i = 0; i < featureLength; i++) {
        inp = inputs.get(i);
        wh = weights.get(i);
        gradient = (out - (double) targetOutput) * inp;
        wh -= learningRate * gradient;
        weights.set(i, wh);
    }

    //update bias
    gradient = (out - targetOutput) * 1;
    bias -= learningRate * gradient;
}
```

I tested it on [this dataset](https://github.com/animesh-agarwal/Machine-Learning/blob/master/LogisticRegression/data/marks.txt)

Comment: What do you mean by it failed to learn at all. I see you are using gradient descent to aproximate the weights. If you say that Logical OR and AND get good results, it might be that your model is too simple and can't fit the data well. Unfortunately, LR is a very simple model and is prone to underfitting. You might wanna a try a more complex model such as a decision tree

Comment: If you have problems aproximating the results, maybe your learning rate is too high. When using gradient descent you need to repeat the gradient step multiple times to aproximate the weights correctly

Comment: The program classifies almost all the data as positive (accepted) with only few samples classified as negative (rejected). I believe if straight line is drawn in the data, there would be more negative class.

Comment: After I tried a smaller learning rate (0.0001) and trained 100K times, the classification accuracy improved. Yes, learning rate made a difference.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having with Logistic Regression is called underfitting, this is a very common problem for simple machine learning models. By this I mean that the model does not adjust correctly to the data. There are different reasons for this to happen:

- The model is to simple (or the dataset is too complicated)
- Your weights aren't correctly approximated

The first problem can be solved by increasing the capacity/complexity of your model(with LR this is not possible), or choosing a more complex one.  One problem that LR has is that it can only handle correctly linearly separable data, otherwise it will have problems giving correct predictions (XOR for example is not linearly separable).

To solve the second problem you might wanna use another method other than gradient descent to calculate the value of the weights. Although, if you want to use gradient descent your have to adjust some hyper parameters. Gradient descent works by trying to find the global minima of the loss/cost function, this means that it tries to find the correct answer by making small steps toward the direction with the steepest slope. To better approximate the weights you can lower the learning rate(this will require more iterations). You can also change the type of initialization for the weights, a better starting point means a faster convergence. Finally you can change your loss function.

Hope that help!